# sharepoint 2010 rest api javascript error: 5009 sys is undefined

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jquery, rest, listdata.svc

I am running into something that I haven't really seen before, and I have been using this approach quite a bit lately for a variety of pages. SharePoint 2010 javascript using REST API to grab data:

```
getContent("http://myServer/sites/mySite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Announcements", thisCallback)

function getContent(whatURL, callback)
{
     var request = new Sys.Net.WebRequest();
     request.set_httpVerb("GET");
     request.set_url(whatURL);
     request.get_headers()["Accept"] = "application/json";
     request.add_completed(callback);
     request.invoke();
}
```

and parse json and process with callback. but now i am getting console error "Sys is undefined" and I am using the same approach within the same site on different pages and it works? any ideas? just for checking i would add a simple callback and it still doesn't work

```
function thisCallback(response, eventArgs)
{
      // wish i could get some results to work with
}
```

appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just in case anyone else runs into this I figured out what was going on:

I usually create multiple custom aspx pages in SP2010 and never really ran into this issue before. When I do, I always add the scriptlink back in:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="SP.js" defer="true" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>
```

but it appears that you must also include a generic form tag for security reasons. when you create a blank aspx page its already there, guess I just happened to accidentally remove it on this page. After I wrapped everything in a simple generic form tag it all worked again (REST & SP JSOM):

```
<form id='form1' runat='server'>
```